# React Use Context. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'alert' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I imported alertContext to use alert. But it keeps on giving error.
Here's is my main app.js file :

```
import './App.css';
import {
  HashRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import NoteState from './context/notes/NoteState';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
import Login from './components/Login';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import alertContext from './context/alert/alertContext';

function App() {
  const {alert} = useContext(alertContext);
  
  return (
    <NoteState>
        <HashRouter>
          <Navbar />
          <Alert alert={alert}/>
          <div className="container">
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} >  </Route>
              <Route exact path="/Login" element={<Login />} > </Route>\
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
    </NoteState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my login file where I want to show alert when a user successfully logged in.
login.js :

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import alertContext from '../context/alert/alertContext';


const Login = () => {

    const context = useContext(alertContext);
    const {showAlert} = context;
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/loginuser";
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password }), 
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);

        if (json.success) {
            // Save the authToken and redirect
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.authToken);
            navigate("/");
            showAlert("Logged in Successfully" , "success")
        }
        else {
            showAlert("Invalid Credentials" , "danger")
        }
    }

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1> Login </h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input value={credentials.email} onChange={onChange} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" name='email' aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
                    <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input value={credentials.password} onChange={onChange} type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name='password' />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Login</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Here is my alert.js file :

```
export default function Alert(props) {
  return (
      <div style={{height:'45px'}}>   
      
      { props.alert && 
          <div className={`alert alert-${props.alert.type} alert-dismissible fade show`} role="alert">
              <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong> : {props.alert.msg}
          </div> }
      </div>
  ) 
}
```

Here is my alertContext :

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const alertContext = createContext();

export default alertContext;
```

And finally here is my AlertState :

```
import AlertContext from './alertContext';
import { useState } from 'react';

const alertState = (props) => {

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
        msg : message, 
        type : type
    })
  }
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={[alert, setAlert ,showAlert]}>
      {props.children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default alertState
```

The error is coming only when after I created this new context for Alert before this the application was error free. Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your AlertState file, you are storing value in an array `value={[alert, setAlert ,showAlert]}`. You are doing object destruction. In order to make it work, change value param to object `value={{alert, setAlert ,showAlert}}`.

Comment: After doing this it's showing : Cannot destructure property 'alert' of 'Context' as it is undefined.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'alert' of 'Context' as it is undefined.

Comment: In case you want to use the context in App file then you will have to wrap the App with the context. I could not find where you have initiated AlertSate. Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Code? A GitHub repo or something similar?

Comment: What if I have to add 2 context, so I have to wrap my app.js file with 2 states ? Like I am already using a NoteState in app.js , so If I want to use AlertState too in my app.js, So should I write AlertState after NoteState and close it just before ending of NoteState?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap multiple contexts around a component.